# PDFBox Rotating all content of an existing PDF by 90 degrees

Tags: java, pdfbox

As the title states, I am trying to rotate a pdf Page from landscape to portrait or vice versa while keeping all existing formatting.

I have tried numerous ways/guides both on stack overflow and outside, including reading existing documentation. The answer unfortunately, still eludes me.

Its easy enough to say set Rotation of a PDFPage eg (page.setRotation(90)).
Or set Rotation via Matrix and Content Stream. However none seem to work as required.

```java
Iterator < PDDocument > iterator = pages.listIterator();
PDDocument temp = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    temp = iterator.next();

    -(..Code goes Here..) -

    /** Set Page rotation test 1**/
    PDPage page = temp.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
    page.setRotation(90);

    /** Set Page rotation test 2**/
    PDPage page = temp.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
    PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(temp, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false);
    Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 0, 0);
    cs.transform(matrix);
    cs.close();

    -(..Other tests etc..) -

    String filePath = "....filePath"
    temp.save(filePath);
    temp.close();
}
```

Comment: *"However none seem to work as required."* - In which way do they not do so? Please show the actual result and sketch the expected one.

Comment: Turns out, it was my mistake, the pdf rotation did work as expected, this wasn't the issue after all, something further down the line broke the expected result. For anyone else, either of the test examples should rotate a pdf by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 4):

First Check page is Rotated or Not. and then rotate the page.

```java
PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
if ((pageSize.getWidth() <= pageSize.getHeight()) && (page.getRotation() == 90 || page.getRotation() == 270)) {
    page.setRotation(0); //Rotate Landscape
} else
    page.setRotation(90); //Rotate Portrait
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example in the question is the answer, the mistake I made was not checking each stage of the project. For anyone stuck on this issue, the example will rotate a pdf by 90 degrees.